# How to convert float numbers to local Money Format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert `float` number type to local `money` format but SQL Server does not accept my convert function.

Here my converting call:

```
FORMAT(360.3678, 'c', 'tr-TR')
```

So output should like this:

```
36.036,78
```

But its getting error with this:

> 'FORMAT' is not recognized built-in function name.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: `FORMAT` is only available in SQL Server **2012** and newer - which version are you using?

Comment: First of all: money should never be a float/real but either an int (amount in cents for example) or even better: the datatype MONEY (or any other fit type from the "Exact Numerics" table [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)). Second: formatting etc. is best left for the UI (or: "View"). Your application has more (specific) knowledge than your SQL server does about the user's locale, preferences etc. (e.g. "context") which may, for example, include preferred number of decimals to display/export etc. Use SQL for **storage** of your data, use your app. to handle the rest